# HTTP Post Rest variable in the api returns 0

Tags: jakarta-ee, jaxb, http-post, jersey-2.0

Disclaimer : I may be missing some fundamentals of J2ee/Jersey programming.

For some reason departureYear gets `0`. I wonder why.

**Request**

> http://localhost:8080/myendpoint/api/BOM/BLR/0/3/9/2015/6/10/2015/1/1/1/1

**Request Junit Code**

```
@Test
public void test1PostSearch() throws Exception {
    ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
    Client client = Client.create(config);
    URI url = UriBuilder
            .fromUri(
                    "http://"
                            + LOCALHOST
                            + "/myendpoint/api/BOM/BLR/"
                            + FlightSearchType.OneWay.ordinal()
                            + "/3/9/2015" + "/6/10/2015/"
                            + CabinClass.Economy.ordinal() + "/1/1/1")
            .build();
    WebResource service = client.resource(url);
    System.out.println(url);
    String status = (String) service.type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).post(
            String.class, new UserNamePassword("clientID", "password"));
    assertNotNull(status);
}
```

** Server Side (Jersey 2.x) **

```
@POST
@Path("api/{origin}/{destination}/{flightSearchType}/{departureDayOfMonth}/{departureMonthOfYear}/{departureYear}/{returnDayOfMonth}/{returnMonthOfYear}/{returnYear}/{cabinClass}/{adultCount}/{childCount}/{infantCount}")
@Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
public Response search(@PathParam("origin") String origin,
        @PathParam("destination") String destination,
        @PathParam("flightSearchType") int flightSearchType,
        @PathParam("departureDayOfMonth") int departureDayOfMonth,
        @PathParam("departureMonthOfYear") int departureMonthOfYear,
        @PathParam("depatureYear") int depatureYear,
        @PathParam("returnDayOfMonth") int returnDayOfMonth,
        @PathParam("returnMonthOfYear") int returnMonthOfYear,
        @PathParam("returnYear") int returnYear,
        @PathParam("cabinClass") int cabinClass,
        @PathParam("adultCount") int adultCount,
        @PathParam("childCount") int childCount,
        @PathParam("infantCount") int infantCount,
        JAXBElement<UserNamePassword> userNamePassword) {

    log.debug("EndPointConsolidation " + depatureYear + ":" + returnYear);
```

**Output log**

```
  0    [http-bio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG com.EndPointConsolidation  - EndPointConsolidation 0:2015
```

**Question**

Why is departureYear 0 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly mistake, I changed from

```
    @PathParam("departureMonthOfYear") int departureMonthOfYear,
    @PathParam("depatureYear") int depatureYear,
    @PathParam("returnDayOfMonth") int returnDayOfMonth,
```

to

```
    @PathParam("departureMonthOfYear") int departureMonthOfYear,
    @PathParam("depa**r**tureYear") int depa**r**tureYear,
    @PathParam("returnDayOfMonth") int returnDayOfMonth,
```

Missed an `r` :).